# How to display probabilities for all classes in Yolo, even if they are very small?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo, darknet

Using yolo Darknet by AlexeyAB

I have 2 classes: notouch and overpack - levels of tobacco in hookah bows. I have good accuracy, but the problem is that yolo displays most relevant class and it's probability. Is there any chance to display all available classes and their availabilities in the output?

Comment: what code do you use?

Comment: Did you fine-tune the model with some custom training datasets? If I remember correctly you can set a confidence threshold as a parameter. Try to lower it (or even set it to zero) to get all predicted results.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for YoloV8 models:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO(r"C:\PathToYourModel\model.pt")

# Predict a class of an image
results = model(r"C:\PathToYourImage\image.jpg")

# Print the result
if results[0].probs[0] > results[0].probs[1]:
    print("First class")
else:
    print("Second class")
```

Also you can see every attribute of the Result class by using following command:

```
print(results[0].__doc__)
```